# Develop an iOS app for website (like News reader app)

Tags: ios

I have a website that publish news

I want to develop an iOS app that support website above like as a news reader. Readers can read, comment, like, share / email / save article via app. They don't need browsers (Safari, Chrome,...) on iOS.

I have no idea how client (iOS app) can get data from server (website), how can they communicate together ?

Thanks !

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Comment: I imagine that Google searches for things like "objective c web service client" or "consume web service in iOS app" are going to return a *lot* of results.

Comment: Over 3 million to be more precise!

Comment: I know about 'web service' and how to consume it from iOS. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking for is called a `web service` (provided by the source of the information (CNN, BBC, etc). If they do not have a public web service or rss feed you cannot allow people access to their data.

iOS has the ability to "consume" web services.

Nobody is going to just give you the code to write this in iOS. However once you get started on it and you have specific issues you can always come back here with specific questions and most people in the Stack Overflow community that knows will gladly help you out

Comment: "If they do not have a public web service or rss feed you cannot allow people access to their data." <= yes, this is my problem.

rss feed is not enough.

Comment: Website based on WordPress Framework. I have 2 choices:

1, build functions that are return data (posts) as XML or JSON
2, try some plugin to do (1) for me (like JSON API plugin)

I have no enough experience in this case and hope you can give me advice (1 or 2) ?

XML / JSON which is best for an iOS ?

Thanks !

Comment: ios can consume XML or JSON, its your call which one you want to use. It will have to be coded a little differently for each XML vs JSON.